# carouselSelect in V2 - everything like in doc but it doesn't work

Tags: dialogflow-es

I read a documentation and saw the format of carousel Select (API V2)

```
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
    "platform": "FACEBOOK",
    "carouselSelect": {
      "items": [
        {
          "info": {
            "key": "Pologne"
          },
          "title": "Varsovie",
          "description": "Prices are starting from 204",
          "image": {
            "imageUri": "https://bucketeer-2aea38ff-6103-4b82-a7e2-760c5feac625.s3.amazonaws.com/public/url_z/PL-sky/WARS-sky/1.jpg"
          }
        },
        {
          "info": {
            "key": "Turquie"
          },
          "title": "Istanbul",
          "description": "Prices are starting from 229",
          "image": {
            "imageUri": "https://bucketeer-2aea38ff-6103-4b82-a7e2-760c5feac625.s3.amazonaws.com/public/url_z/TR-sky/ISTA-sky/1.jpg"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "platform": "SLACK",
    "carouselSelect": {
      "items": [
        {
          "info": {
            "key": "Pologne"
          },
          "title": "Varsovie",
          "description": "Prices are starting from 204",
          "image": {
            "imageUri": "https://bucketeer-2aea38ff-6103-4b82-a7e2-760c5feac625.s3.amazonaws.com/public/url_z/PL-sky/WARS-sky/1.jpg"
          }
        },
        {
          "info": {
            "key": "Turquie"
          },
          "title": "Istanbul",
          "description": "Prices are starting from 229",
          "image": {
            "imageUri": "https://bucketeer-2aea38ff-6103-4b82-a7e2-760c5feac625.s3.amazonaws.com/public/url_z/TR-sky/ISTA-sky/1.jpg"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
],
```

But it, unfortunately doesn't work. Do you have any ideas why? When I use Card object from the doc is worked fine. Also if I add fulfillmentText the bot displays text

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about what types of rich messages Dialogflow supports here in the [docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages). Dialogflow supports Text, Cards, Images, Suggestion Chips (Quick Replies), and Payloads (Platform-specific responses).

For the content of the custom payload please see the target platform documentation (Google Assistant, Slack, Facebook messenger, etc.)

Actions on Google, however, supports more [rich responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses), such as carousels, etc.